# Is this character name in Rise and Fall of D.O.D.O. a mistake or a hint?

Tags: the-rise-and-fall-of-d.o.d.o

Spoilers for *[The Rise and Fall of D.O.D.O.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32075825-the-rise-and-fall-of-d-o-d-o)* I'm reading the hardcover version.

> D.O.D.O. has an advisor, Dr. Constantine Rudge. His first name is mentioned on page 148. However, by page 483, a Dr. Cornelius Rudge is mentioned - and specifically said to have "been on the project since the beginning." This seems to imply this is the same character. However, by page 527, it's back to "Constantine." I believe it remains "Constantine" until page 704, when he's referred to again as "Cornelius."

Given the other events of the book, like,

> The Pentagon having been originally named the "Trapezoid", subsequently changing to "the Pentagon" through other changes in history

Is this some clue to the plot of the book? Or just a mistake?

Comment: The change also occurs in the ebook version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My reading of the novel is that the change is intentional and kept slight so as to fit in with the conceit of time travel resulting in such small changes.